# How to give all permisions on a self-signed applet

Tags: java, applet

I need to know how set, when user accepts to run the applet, all permissions.

This is about an application where my user trusts absolutely on the application, so he will give all permissions.

The issue is we always have problems with permissions and the applet cannot sign and send the XML it is supposed to.

Sometimes we have to restart computer to permissions work.

**I don't want to change the java.policy file, I want to put all permissions inside the applet.**

Any help would be very very appreciated.

Comment: What would be the easiest options?

Comment: Take a look into Java Web Start.

Comment: One of the easiest options is to sign it with an official certificate...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch  JWS apps. have the same security manager as applets.  So it comes back to *"In short, you can't."*